# Resolution 2880 x 1800 not available in Windows 8 (VMware Fusion 5)

Tags: macbook-pro, vmware, resolution

I've installed Windows 8 in a VMware Fusion 5 virtual machine. Actually, I upgraded the virtual machine from VMware Fusion 4.

I'd like to set my retina MacBook Pro's resolution to the display's native resolution **2880 x 1800**, but Windows doesn't offer the option for that resolution. The maximum is 2560 x 1920 (or 2650 x 1600).

Is there a way to let Windows know that I'm using a 2880 x 1800 display? Do I have to install a monitor driver in Windows?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Per VMware's [Retina KB article](http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/search.do?cmd=displayKC&docType=kc&externalId=2034670&sliceId=1&docTypeID=DT_KB_1_1&dialogID=417860362&stateId=1%200%20417870485), you can enable 1:1 pixel mapping for a Fusion 5 VM by going to **Settings → Display** and checking **Use full resolution for Retina display**.

If after that you don't see the 2880x1800 resolution, you need to make some manual tweaks, following [this KB article](http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=1003):

1. Open the `.vmx` file in a text editor.
2. Add the line `svga.autodetect = "FALSE"`
3. Add (or update if it already exists) `svga.vramSize = 20774912`
4. Add (or update if they already exist) `svga.maxWidth = 2880` and `svga.maxHeight = 1800`
5. Save the file and open your Windows VM.
6. In the Windows registry (Start → Run → `regedit`) search for the `vmx_svga` key. Per the article, "The correct key has several sub-keys, but it is the main key that should be edited."
7. Create a new string value (REG_SZ) named Resolution.x, where x is one higher than the highest number listed.
8. Enter 2880x1800 as the new value.
9. Restart Windows.
10. Open the Display Control Panel to change to your new resolution

Answer (score 0):

Can you try if [VMware Fusion Technology Preview 2012](http://communities.vmware.com/community/vmtn/beta/fusiontp2012) does the trick?
On the [What's new?](http://communities.vmware.com/docs/DOC-18666) they list "Added support for Retina-Display resolution with Windows 7 & Windows 8 (Settings > Display)"